# Servicestack service not loading

Tags: servicestack

I am lost... What am i missing. I copied a working service and renamed it. the service will not load in service stack. cant access via api and not showing in metadata page...

Code follows

```
    using cbw.service.models.Models;
using ServiceStack;

namespace cbw.service.models.Routes
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Company RTO - Response DataObject with custom Route
    /// </summary>
    [Route("/GetPermission/{Id}", "GET")]
    public class GetPermission : IReturn<GetPermission>
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

    [Route("/Permission", "PUT")]
    public class AddPermission : PostReturn
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int AuditUserId { get; set; }
    }

    [Route("/Permission/{Id}", "PUT")]
    public class UpdatePermission : IReturn<UpdatePermission>
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int AuditUserId { get; set; }
    }

    [Route("/Permission/{Id}", "DELETE")]
    public class DeletePermission : IReturnVoid
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
}



using System;
using cbw.service.models.Models;
using cbw.service.models.Routes;
using ServiceStack;
using ServiceStack.OrmLite;

namespace cbw.service.interfaces.Services
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    //[Authenticate]
    public class SecurityService : Service
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// To insert new permission
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public long AddPermission(AddPermission request)
        {
            var perm = request.ConvertTo<Permission>();
            perm.AuditUserId = Convert.ToInt32(UserInfo.UserSession().UserAuthId);
            return Db.Insert(perm);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// To Update permission
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="request"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public int UpdatePermission(UpdatePermission request)
        {
            using (var trans = Db.OpenTransaction())
            {
                //Insert Historical
                var permissionHist = Db.SingleById<Permission>(request.Id).ConvertTo<PermissionHist>();
                permissionHist.Action = DbAction.Update;

                //update Permission
                var perm = request.ConvertTo<Permission>();
                perm.AuditUserId = Convert.ToInt32(UserInfo.UserSession().UserAuthId);

                var i = Db.Update(perm);
                Db.Insert(permissionHist);

                trans.Commit();
                return i;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// To delete permissions
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="request"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public int DeletePermisssion(DeletePermission request)
        {
            //Insert Historical
            Db.Insert(Db.SingleById<Permission>(request.Id).ConvertTo<PermissionHist>().Action = DbAction.Delete);

            return Db.Delete<Permission>(c => c.Id == request.Id);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The methods of a ServiceStack Service should be the name of the HTTP Verb it should handle, e.g Get/Post/Put/Delete/Patch, etc or `Any` to handle the Request on any Verb.

The response should match what’s in `IReturn<TResponse>` interface marker of the Request DTO which is typically the Response DTO. It **should never** be a raw **value type** like an `int` or `long` but can be a raw **reference type** like a `string` or `byte[]`.

Or if your Request DTO has an `IReturnVoid` interface marker your service method should be `void`.